# Dynamically change event properties on aws cloudformation templates

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

We are building a serverless app using aws and we want to enable lambda warmers only on the production environment.

Our cloudformation parameters:

```yaml
Parameters:
  Environment:
    Description: Environment name
    Type: String

  EnableWarmer:
    Description: Flag to enable/disable warmup Events
    Default: DISABLED
    Type: String
```

Our lambdas yaml file looks like this:

```yaml
MyLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub '${Environment}-my-lambda'
      CodeUri: src
      Handler: lambda.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: Creates a new something
      Layers:
        - !Ref InternalDependencyLayer
        - !Ref ExternalDependencyLayer
      Role: !Ref LambdaRoleArn
      Events:
        Api:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /url
            Method: POST
            RestApiId: !Ref ApiGateway
        WarmingSchedule:
          Type: Schedule
          Properties:
            Enabled: !Ref EnableWarmer
            Schedule: rate(5 minutes)
            Input: '{ "warmer":true,  "concurrency": 2 }'
```

And then we deploy the dev environment with these params:

```yaml
- Key: Environment
  Value: dev

- Key: EnableWarmer
  Value: DISABLED
```

Similarly for the production environment we deploy with these params:

```yaml
- Key: Environment
  Value: production

- Key: EnableWarmer
  Value: ENABLED
```

According to aws documentation parameters can't be of type boolean which is the required type of the enabled attribute of the schedule event.

Fortunately amazon states:

> Enabled Indicates whether the rule is enabled.
>
> To disable the rule, set this property to False.
>
> Type: Boolean
>
> Required: No
>
> AWS CloudFormation compatibility: This property is similar to the
> State property of an AWS::Events::Rule resource. If this property is
> set to True then AWS SAM passes ENABLED, otherwise it passes DISABLED

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-schedule.html

However when we deploy to the dev environment the warmers are enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, **Enabled** must a Boolean variable.

You can still have a String parameter and convert it to Boolean inside the CloudFormation.

```yaml
WarmingSchedule:
  Type: Schedule
    Properties:
      Enabled: !Equals [!Ref EnableWarmer, ENABLED] 
      Schedule: rate(5 minutes)
      Input: '{ "warmer":true,  "concurrency": 2 }'
```

This way you still can send ENABLED or DISABLED as a parameter but the input of WarmingSchedule.Enabled will be a Boolean.

Comment: This made it work, thanks a lot!

However, there is a small issue. If I deploy with the EnableWarmer set to "ENABLED"  and the redeploy with "DISABLED" the warming events will still be attached to the lambdas. 

If I want to disable the warmers from an environment I will first need to delete manualy all the events from the console and the trigger the new deployment.

Comment: this does not work for me in AWS SAM

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the `Enabled` property here seems to be that it does not support using CloudFormation's [`If` function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-conditions.html#intrinsic-function-reference-conditions-if) and a [Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/conditions-section-structure.html) to do something like that:

```
WarmingSchedule:
  Enabled: !If [WarmerCondition, true, false]
```

(At least I couldn't figure it out, but maybe I just did something wrong) This is similar to what [@raul-barreto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5337649/raul-barreto) suggests with `!Equals`. However, in my tests it always sets the rule's status to `ENABLED`.

It seems like there are two options left what you can do:

a) (Not recommended) Copy the CloudFormation code of your Lambda function and have a second one available in your CloudFormation resources. Now set a condition to both of them so you only create one of them, depending on your environment. Note: I don't say this is a good approach but it'd be possible. Problems are you have to maintain the definition of both Lambda functions and if you repeat this approach, you'll faster reach [CloudFormations template size limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cloudformation-limits.html).

b) If you want to make sure you have a minimum number of instances available to your function (at least that's what I interpret from your question), consider using [AWS Lambda's Provisioned Concurrency feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) instead. You can define it like this in your AWS Lambda function using SAM:

```
MyLambda:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
    AutoPublishAlias: 'LATEST' #Setting AutoPublishAlias is important, otherwise you can not use provisioned concurrency
    ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
      ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: 2
```

This snippet will provision concurrency for the function's alias 'LATEST' which points to the latest version of your function. Read more about [AutoPublishAlias in SAM](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/safe_lambda_deployments.rst#instant-traffic-shifting-using-lambda-aliases) (Note: the link's content is written in the context of traffic shifting but it explains what the property does). It makes sure that you always have 2 instances of your Lambda functions available.

Comment: Yeah I know, I had dismissed myself the (a) option previously. 

In response to your (b) recommendation, I don't think that Provisioned Concurrency  will help in our case.  A portion of our lambdas will be used by a lot of endusers all around the world and we want to eliminate the cold start latency of those lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution works, but as stated in comments, it is a bit difficult to control the enabling and disabling of the event. The following seems to work in a more robust way.

```yaml
      Events:
        Scheduler:
          Type: Schedule 
          Properties:
            Schedule: !If [EnableWarmer, "rate(5 minutes)",
                           "cron(00 00 01 01 ? 1970)"]
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! I was banging my head against the wall because I could not make the Enabled property work with !If. This works!

Comment: this does not work for me in AWS SAM